# How to send data to server through headers using signalr_client flutter

Tags: asp.net-core, flutter, signalr-hub

I need some help ...I am using a flutter package signalr_client for 
real time web functionality to flutter app.So i want to send data to server either Http headers or query string . There is no option for signalr_client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got answer. I sent timezone through query string by `http:192.168.0.100/Chat?tmz=330'`.And i get 
by calling `context.Request.Query["tmz"]`

Comment: I need to send it as a header. Can you help me with that